# How can I make an interactive button in PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pygame

I want to make a button in [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) but when I look it up literally no code works and I am on the verge of eating sand. Please I just need a simple code to make a clickable button.

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea of a button includes knowing the x, y, width and height of your (presumably) rectangular button.

What you're trying to do is figure out if you mouse is within the coordinates of where your button is located and if the left mouse button is being pressed.

Here is a generic button class for doing exactly that:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, text, centre=True):
        self.colour = (0, 0, 0)
        self.text = text
        self.text = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 30).render(text, 1, self.colour)

        if centre:
            self.x = int(x - self.text.get_width() // 2)
            self.y = int(y - self.text.get_height() // 2)
        else:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        self.width = int(self.text.get_width())
        self.height = int(self.text.get_height())

    # draw method which displays the text and border of the button
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 2)
        win.blit(self.text, (self.x, self.y))

    # method which returns true when the mouse is over the button and false when it isn't
    def is_over(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

    # method for detecting whether or not the button has been pressed and returns true if it has
    @staticmethod
    def is_pressed():
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if mouse[0]:
            return True

        return False
```

Instantiate a new object of the button class like follows:

```
btn = Button(
    x=0, 
    y=0, 
    text="Example text which will display in top left corner", 
    centre=False
)
```

This might help you out a bit, you might need to edit the class to suit your use case.

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? When copying code, add at least a reference to the source.

Comment: It's my own code from one of my own private repos

Comment: At least the `is_over` function is form a tutorial. In any case, the code can be greatly simplified. Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) objects and [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) . Center the button by stetting the `center` attribute.